# PivotTable Nested Columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am interested in grouping columns together by a common factor. Below is a basic example:

[image: Example]

I'm interested in nesting the vehicle brands under the categories `Luxury` and `Frugal`. Thus making them collapsible like the rows can be. This is a basic example whereas the data I'm planning to work with this has thousands of rows of data similar to a layout as these rows and possibly 50-100 columns that could be collapsible into 5-10. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your data should be in the form of a table with only one row of headers if you want to use it as the source for a pivottable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been suggested, adding Luxury/Frugal as a column in your source data would achieve what you require. However that would require substantial rearrangement, make your source data occupy a much larger range and not give an ideal result because adding just the one column, while allowing filtering by column in the PivotTable, each filter view would still show all columns (though mostly blank).

So completely "flattening" the source data may be a better choice, if to rearrange the source data at all:

[image: SO29423652 first example]

The fields arranged like so:

[image: SO29423652 second example]

Comment: While I think this is the correct answer to the question and simple example at hand, from a time perspective, it is probably too costly to make this arrangement. For example, working with 6000 rows and two 50 column headers using this method would create an exorbitant amount of rows. Thank you for taking the time to answer.